# Is it possible to avoid specifying a column list in a SQL Server CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Is it possible to avoid specifying a column list in a SQL Server CTE?

I'd like to create a CTE from a table that has many columns so that the structure is identical.  There probably is a way to accomplish this without relisting every column name.

I've tried (unsuccessfully):

```
with pay_cte as
(select * from payments)
select * from pay_cte
```

I'm encouraged in my quest by this statement in the msdn documentation:
The list of column names is optional only if distinct names for all resulting columns are supplied in the query definition.

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: You know, it’s really a good idea to end your statement with a semicolon; this is not only the SQL standard, it’s also recommended by Microsoft. In particular, you get into trouble with the `with` syntax if you get careless with semicolons.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, assuming you mean that you don't have to name every column in the `with cte(Col1, Col2) as` section.

You can easily try this yourself with a very simple test query along the lines of:

```
with cte as
(
    select *
    from sys.tables
)
select *
from cte
```

Comment: Hi Dave - Thanks for this succinct, accurate, and useful answer.

Comment: @JoelBenjamin  Thanks :)  For the benefit of other users with the same question, please mark this as the correct answer if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: I would mark this as the correct answer if I saw any option to do so.  Perhaps stackoverflow doesn't give one the option to do so to newbies like me.  It states that my upvotes don't count until I accumulate 15 points.

Comment: @JoelBenjamin  Upvoting and accepting an answer are two different things.  You should be able to accept this as the answer.

Comment: That does not work for recursive CTEs (at least, under Oracle).

Comment: @XavierDury I'm not sure why you would expect it to, given this is a question and answer explicitly relating to SQL Server

Comment: I'm not understanding something: this is exactly what the OP said didn't work. Of course, assuming you get the table name correct, this *will* work, but it's still confusing: We have a question saying "I want to achieve X. I tried A and it didn't work" and an answer saying "You can do this by doing A"... and then the OP says the answer was helpful. What am I missing?

Comment: @Martha the query included in the question was edited in after this answer was submitted.  My presumption is that the query in the question is not actually a functionality equivalent example of what the OP initially tried.

Answer (score 0):

@iamdave is a simple and straightforward answer but it does not always work.

I found it will failed if a column has no name or duplicate columns.

In these situations, column names are needed. However, all they need to do is line up like with an insert statement.

```
With X_CTE (dateEdit, dateCreated, customer, createdBy, contactPerson, type, status,datePublished, editedBy, invalidated) as 
(
    SELECT GETDATE(), GETDATE(), 'ERS','SYSTEM',en.person, 'Email', 'Final', en.dateEdit, en.person, 0
        FROM entry as en Join 
        entryClass as ec on en.entryID = ec.entryID join 
        classifications as cl on ec.classID = cl.classID
        WHERE en.[invalidated] = 0 and cl.classType = 'beeep' and Code = 'TT11'
)
select * from ERS_Email_CTE
```

however, "as statements" maybe valuable to prevent errors.